# WaterfallDialog choiceprompt working in emulator but not working in directline webchannel in Bot framework v4

Tags: c#, botframework

I have recently migrated my project from bot framework v3 to bot V4.
I have FeedbackDialog file in this i have implemented waterfallsteps, choiceprompts.
Everything and the flow is working correctly in Emulator.
But it is not working properly means the flow is not working fine in Webchannel
Please provide the solution to this problem.

Here is my code.

```
public FeedbackDialog() : base(nameof(FeedbackDialog))
    {
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt("ShowChoicePrompt") { Style = ListStyle.HeroCard });
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
       {
            StartAsync,
            MessageReceivedAsync,
            ResumeAfterPositiveFeedbackSelectionClarification
       }));

         InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
    }

    public async Task<DialogTurnResult> StartAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

    {

        var reply = ((Activity)stepContext.Context.Activity).CreateReply(BotConstants.feedbackRequestText);

        reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
        {
            Actions = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction(){ Title = "", Type=ActionTypes.PostBack, Value=BotConstants.positiveFeedbackValue },
                new CardAction(){ Title = "", Type=ActionTypes.PostBack, Value=BotConstants.negativeFeedbackValue }
            }
        };
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
        return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
        // return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);

    }

    public async Task<DialogTurnResult> MessageReceivedAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var data=stepContext.Result;
        var res = stepContext.Result;
       // string res= Convert.ToString(data.GetType().GetProperty("Synonym").GetValue(data, null));
        var feedbackDetails = (FeedbackData)stepContext.Options;

        var userFeedback =Convert.ToString(res);
       // var userFeedback = feedbackDetails.userFeedback;
        string userQuestion = feedbackDetails.userQuestion;
        string intent = feedbackDetails.intent;
        int Id = feedbackDetails.Id;

        if (userFeedback.Contains(BotConstants.positiveFeedbackValue) || userFeedback.Contains(BotConstants.negativeFeedbackValue))
        {
            // create telemetry client to post to Application Insights 
            TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
            telemetry.InstrumentationKey = Configuration.CDPOSConfigurationManager.GetAppSetting("InstrumentationKey");
            RequestRepository requestRepository = new RequestRepository();

            if (userFeedback.Contains(BotConstants.positiveFeedbackValue))
            {
                // post feedback to App Insights
                var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Question", userQuestion },
                    {"LuisIntent", intent },
                    {"Vote", "Yes" }
                    // add properties relevant to your bot 
                };

                telemetry.TrackEvent("Yes-Vote", properties);

                var chatFeedback = true;
                //requestRepository.AddChatbotEntryToDB(userQuestion, intent, chatFeedback);
                requestRepository.updateChatFeedbackStatus(Id, chatFeedback);

                var options = BotConstants.positiveFeedbackOption;
                var descriptions = BotConstants.positiveFeedbackOptionDesc;
                Activity textPrompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply(BotConstants.positiveFeedbackResponse);


                List<Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices.Choice> choices = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices.Choice>()
                {
                       new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices.Choice { Value = BotConstants.YeshaveAnotherQuestionOption, Synonyms = new List<string> { "Yes" } },
                       new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices.Choice { Value = BotConstants.NothankyouOption, Synonyms = new List<string> { "No" }}
                };

                try
                {
                    await stepContext.PromptAsync("ShowChoicePrompt", new PromptOptions {Prompt= MessageFactory.Text(BotConstants.positiveFeedbackResponse), Choices= choices }, cancellationToken);
                    return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await stepContext.PromptAsync("ShowChoicePrompt", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(BotConstants.positiveFeedbackResponse), Choices = choices }, cancellationToken);
                    return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
                }

            }
            else if (userFeedback.Contains(BotConstants.negativeFeedbackValue))
            {
                var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Question", userQuestion },
                    {"LuisIntent", intent },
                    {"Vote", "Yes" }
                    // add properties relevant to your bot 
                };

                telemetry.TrackEvent("No-Vote", properties);
                var chatFeedback = false;

                //requestRepository.AddChatbotEntryToDB(userQuestion, intent, chatFeedback);
                requestRepository.updateChatFeedbackStatus(Id, chatFeedback);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(BotConstants.negativeFeedbackResponse);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(BotConstants.logTicketResponse);


                var options = BotConstants.negativeFeedbackOption;
                var descriptions = BotConstants.negativeFeedbackDesc;


                List<Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices.Choice> NegativeChoices = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices.Choice>()
                {
                       new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices.Choice { Value = BotConstants.logTicket, Synonyms = new List<string> { BotConstants.logTicketOption } },
                       new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices.Choice { Value = BotConstants.rephraseQuestionOption, Synonyms = new List<string> { BotConstants.rephraseQuestionOption }}
                };

                try
                {

                    await stepContext.PromptAsync("ShowChoicePrompt", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(BotConstants.positiveFeedbackResponse), Choices = NegativeChoices }, cancellationToken);
                    return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await stepContext.PromptAsync("ShowChoicePrompt", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(BotConstants.question), Choices = NegativeChoices }, cancellationToken);
                    return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(RootDialog), null, cancellationToken);
            // no feedback, return to main dialog
           // return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(userFeedback, cancellationToken);
            //return stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(userFeedback, cancellationToken);
        }
        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(userFeedback, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ResumeAfterPositiveFeedbackSelectionClarification(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var data = stepContext.Result;
        if (stepContext.Result != null)
        {
            string selection = Convert.ToString(data.GetType().GetProperty("Synonym").GetValue(data, null));
            // var selection = stepContext.Result;
            if (selection == BotConstants.YeshaveAnotherQuestionOption || selection == BotConstants.haveAnotherQuestionOption || selection == BotConstants.rephraseQuestionOption)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(BotConstants.askAnotherQuestion);
            }
            else
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(BotConstants.logaTicketResponse);
            }
        }
       return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
    }









public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
               // builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                builder.RegisterType<MessagesController>().InstancePerRequest();
                // The ConfigurationCredentialProvider will retrieve the MicrosoftAppId and
                // MicrosoftAppPassword from Web.config
                builder.RegisterType<ConfigurationCredentialProvider>().As<ICredentialProvider>().SingleInstance();

                // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled.
                builder.RegisterType<AdapterWithErrorHandler>().As<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter>().SingleInstance();

                // The Memory Storage used here is for local bot debugging only. When the bot
                // is restarted, everything stored in memory will be gone.
                IStorage dataStore = new MemoryStorage();

                // Create Conversation State object.
                // The Conversation State object is where we persist anything at the conversation-scope.
                var conversationState = new ConversationState(dataStore);
                builder.RegisterInstance(conversationState).As<ConversationState>().SingleInstance();

                // Register the main dialog, which is injected into the DialogBot class
                builder.RegisterType<RootDialog>().SingleInstance();

                // Register the DialogBot with RootDialog as the IBot interface
                builder.RegisterType<DialogBot<RootDialog>>().As<IBot>();

                var container = builder.Build();
                var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
                config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
            }
```

Comment: What exactly is happening in the Web Channel ? What error are you getting or can you further explain by comparing what is supposed to happen and what is actually happen

Comment: I am not getting any error in web channel but in emulator after clicking feedback button it is going to the next step but in webchannel it is not going .

Comment: @naguluvemula - Is your bot using memory storage? (You will have to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply)

Comment: @Kyle Delaney - My bot don't have memory storage using conversationState only

Comment: @ Kyle Delaney - My bot don't have memory storage using conversationState only

Comment: @naguluvemula - `conversationState` is a type a bot state, not a type of storage. Bot state classes are configured to use a storage class that implements `IStorage`. If you show us the `ConfigureServices` method in your Startup class then we might be able to figure out what kind of storage you're using. Please refer to the docs for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state

Comment: @ Kyle Delaney - please find the below method i used for configure. please see my edited code

Comment: @naguluvemula - We can see that you're using memory storage. Please try using Cosmos DB or Azure Blob storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage

Comment: @naguluvemula - Are you still working on this?

Comment: yes @Kyle Delaney

Comment: @naguluvemula - Did you try changing your storage?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney - I used ESO Federation to get the user information there is no use of storages in my project i already implemented blob storage to store the files

Comment: @Kyle Delaney - my problem is based on above code in "MessageReceivedAsync" i have called PromptAync method with choices. After displaying the choice options when i click on specific choice it has to go to the next waterfall step "ResumeAfterPositiveFeedbackSelectionClarification" this flow is working correctly in Emulator but it is not working in channel i am using directline channel

Comment: @naguluvemula - Do you see in your `Register` method where it says `IStorage dataStore = new MemoryStorage();`? Your dialogs depend on dialog state to work, and dialog state depends on bot state and bot state depends on storage. Memory storage cannot be used in deployed bots, so that is very likely why your dialog is only working when you test locally. If you'd like to see if you can get your locally-running bot to work on Direct Line then you can try ngrok: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/

Comment: @ Kyle Delaney - yes i have Debugged the Channel locally using ngrok the dialog flow is working without any any issue but when i tested with webchat i am facing the issue

Comment: @naguluvemula - You're talking about two different things. Local versus deployed is just where the bot is running, and Emulator versus Web Chat is the channel client you're using to communicate with the bot. You seem to be conflating the question of where the bot is running with the question of what channel client you're using. You can use Emulator to talk to either local or deployed bots, and you can use Web Chat to talk to either local or deployed bots, and the same goes for any other channel client as explained in the blog post I linked. Did you try using Web Chat with your local bot?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney - Thanks for your information i used Webchat with my local bot using ngrock as explained above i was getting retry message for the first time but i am able to get the response the dialog flow also working correctly in webchat

Comment: @naguluvemula - If you're trying to say that the dialog works correctly on Web Chat when tunneling through ngrok but the dialog works incorrectly on Web Chat when your bot's endpoint is an Azure app service, then this is further evidence that memory storage is your problem. Have you configured your bot to use remote storage yet? Did you follow the link I gave you that explains how to use Cosmos DB and Azure Blob storage? Please follow my instructions because this comment thread has gotten needlessly long.

Comment: Kyle Delaney - i will use remote storage thank you

Comment: @KyleDelaney - Thanks for your advice i used blob storage that solved my issue thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a bot only works when it's running locally, memory storage is very often the issue. When a bot is deployed to an app service, there may be multiple instances of the service running simultaneously to provide high availability, and each instance will have its own memory. Like all REST API's, your bot needs to not rely on memory for the state it accesses across multiple turns. You need external storage so that all instances of the service have access to the same data, and so the data isn't lost when the service restarts. Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state) for more information.